# Add logo to admin menu in my plugin

Tags: plugins, php, admin, css, admin-menu

I want to add a simple piece of code:

```
<img src="logo.png">
```

to the top of the admin menu.
I know how to do it if I am just replacing a logo within an already existing class but there is no adminmenulogo class, how do I do this? Am i taking the wrong approach by using the add_action hook? I am new to developing plugins. Thanks.

```
function my_admin_menu_logo() {
What to put here? :)
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu_logo');
```

**I found a solution. I just added the image as a background to the adminmenuwrap class and added some padding at the top.**

```
#adminmenuwrap {
width: 160px;
background-color: #e7e7e7;
background-image: url("https://www.google.dk/logos/doodles/2015/new-horizons-pluto-flyby-5641113681526784-res.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-top: 50px;
```

Comment: Did you changed the wordpress css file or have you added it on your theme, cuz if you changed wordpress file that will be override when a wordpress update is made?

Comment: No, I have created a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as the first option was loading wired i have come to a better solution.
what we will do in this case is to create a new menu item, put it in first position, give a custom class, needed to add cutom css style for that item. For this we will:

- create a function to add new menu item
- create a function to load custom stylesheet to admin panel
- and create the new css style to override default css for that item

This will be the function to add new menu:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'shomtek_admin_menu');

function shomtek_admin_menu() {
    global $menu;
    $url = 'http://www.shomtek.com/';
    $menu[0] = array( __('SHOMTek'), 'read', $url, 'shomtek-logo', 'shomtek-logo');
}
```

Adding custom stylesheet to wp-admin head

```
add_action('admin_head', 'shomtek_admin_style');

function shomtek_admin_style() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin_style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />';
}
```

At the end the custom style for that menu item

```
#adminmenu a.shomtek-logo{
    display: block;
    background: url(http://www.shomtek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 140px 40px;
    width: 140px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

#adminmenu a.shomtek-logo div.wp-menu-name {
    display: none;
}
```

This is all, tested and it works perfect ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was just about to write that I figured it out, however I do have a question that you may be able to answer, how do I style it? From an external stylesheet or what? Also it seems to be loading weird. :( I have made a gif to show you. [link](http://gyazo.com/b502b4e11df2000952f46925aa7230d1)

Comment: You can load a new stylesheet only for admin. That is because you it need to `z-index` it maybe. But still is a little wired. Im checking it right now and let you know later.

Comment: Oh yeah I realize the z-index part, it is the loading before everything else that freaks me out. Okay, thanks. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: I have tried the z-index part, but it seems to be under the menu no matter what I do.

Comment: @Christoffer please check again cuz i have changed everything i my answer.

Comment: I cannot get it to work. The  . get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin_style.css file does not exist, so I have nowhere to put the css code?

Comment: @ChristofferHansen offcourse, that file doesn't exist, you have to create it, that is based on your template file and folder structure. What you have to do is: create a css file, name it admin_style.css, add the css style that is provided on the answer and put it in root of your template folder. After this change `. get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin_style.css` to `. get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin_style.css`